# UDF to decrypt 256-bit AES using PKCS #5’s in Hive

Tags: encryption, spring-security, hive, cryptography

I have some strings which are encrypted by a Spring boot application using `org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor` which uses a 256-bit AES PKCS #5’s. The encrypted value contains both the salt and the cipher as a JSON.

eg: `{"cipher":"8e93b3eabecdda5ce2cdb2c69ae2c141bb14d086a1b6c8cf5b09cab1179b6291","salt":"ce192103318fcea1"}`

Is it possible to write a UDF in Hive which decrypts this string? If so, how? I'm new to Hive, so I'm completely clueless as to how to do this. I'm running an EMR cluster on AWS.

Comment: I would strongly suggest this is better performed by generic Java. I don't know hadoop, but you probably can execute code given some specific query? Note that PKCS#5 doesn't specify the algorithm configuration itself, I don't see any indication of iteration count or hash algorithm in the JSON string you've given.

Comment: If you have an instance of the matching TextEncryptor used to produce, couldn't you just call TextEncryptor.decrypt()? If not, you'll have figure what encryption algorithm and key derivation algorithm are being used.

Comment: Can you decrypt that stuff with a single static Java method that takes two `String` args? If yes, then you can use the Hive (undocumented) `reflect2` function.

Comment: I didn't want to use Java to decrypt this. I wanted to write a function which does this in hive.